# Call addSubView within layoutSubviews

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

Is it ok to add subviews within a layoutSubviews call?

Given that layoutSubviews is your hook point to customize sub view frame, it's not clear if addition of further sub views may cause problems.

Comment: As the name implies, layoutSubviews is for laying out subviews. You should be adding subviews elsewhere and then laying them out in layoutSubviews.

Comment: From docs: "Your implementation of this method [layoutSubviews] can do any of the following: Adjust the size and position of any immediate subviews. Add or remove subviews or Core Animation layers. [...]" https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/CreatingViews/CreatingViews.html But adding a subview and setting autolayout constraints on it in this method can create infinite loop so you might need to use frames instead of autolayout in this case. Also this method can be called many times so be careful to not add the same thing few times.

Answer (score 6):

You can, but it’s not a great idea—`-layoutSubviews` is meant for *laying out* subviews, not creating them, and it can be called at more or less any time for a whole host of reasons. Creating views there won’t cause problems as long as you keep track of what views you’ve added already and don’t recreate them, but it’s bad practice. Create subviews in your initializer, or lazily as you need them elsewhere, and keep your `-layoutSubviews` as light as possible.

Comment: I wonder what other alternatives there are to add lazily created view as subview beside doing this, only one time, in layoutSubviews. By creating views lazily we don't have to override inits but views have to be added to hierarchy at some point. The question is when ?